# Changing parameters in scikit-learn classifier results in UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-2.7, text, scikit-learn

I have a csv-file with 100k's of lines with a column of free text containing scandinavian characters among others and I'm fitting scikit-learn classifiers to predict True/False (given in another column) for a given piece of text.

I am using this example as a starting point: http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html

The only thing I changed at first is the data, and the training + testing goes fine with useful results.

However, I want to test the liblinear-like LinearSVC classifier, as that might produce better results in some cases. Changing nothing but the classifier to "LinearSVC" or alternatively sticking to SGDClassifier as in the example but changing the loss function to squared_hinge from the default hinge results in

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 312: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am assuming this error must rise from the input csv but cannot understand why the initial example from the url runs smoothly and changing the classifier properties with the exact same input data results in this error. Any ideas why this may be?

Secondly, I am not familiar with Python stack tracing and would appreciate any help on how to debug the error / trace it down to the problematic byte. The stack trace is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-33-2a0e420237f0>", line 48, in <module>
grid_search.fit(data_train.kuvaus, data_train.loukkaantuneita)

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 945, in fit
return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 564, in _fit
for parameters in parameter_iterable

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 768, in __call__
self.retrieve()

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 696, in retrieve
stack_start=1)

  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\format_stack.py", line 417, in format_outer_frames
return '\n'.join(format_records(output[stack_end:stack_start:-1]))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 312: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The *data_train* is Pandas Dataframe with a True/False *data_train.loukkaantuneita* and a free text (supposed to be utf-8) *data_train.kuvaus* column.

Comment: Then post the stack trace here. Also post your code and some sample data if possible]

Comment: @VivekKumar Added stack trace. For the code, it is the same as in the url example above, when everything runs smoothly, and when I change "'clf_loss': (['squared_hinge'])" in the parameters, this results to the UnicodeError, which I don't understand, as I don't change the input text in any way between the two runs.

Comment: Either use a round bracket or square, not both. Use `'clf__n_iter': ('squared_hinge')`.

Comment: So is your problem or not?

Comment: @VivekKumar This is not the problem - actually, Pipeline does not allow the notation ('squared_hinge'), that is only one single parameter inside the round brackets, so ('hinge', 'squared_hinge') works, but for the former notation with only one argument, I get an error "ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (clf__loss) need to be a sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray.", so I assume a list of more than one parameter is implicitly converted to array, but for a single parameter, the square brackets are needed. ['squared_hinge'] works and is cleaner, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put this statements @ the begining of the code and try running:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Weirdly enough, I can't reproduce this error right now. The error may have had to do with a problem with multithreading like this https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5115. I must use only single core computing for my computation not to get suck, and with that, the UnicodeDecodeError seems to have gone for now. Should it reappear, I will try your magic. Thank you.